# Can't get Livewire Events Emit and Listen to work

Tags: laravel, event-listener, laravel-livewire

I am trying to setup an event listener, so that when a child livewire component gets the title updated, it would refresh the parent component to show the update instead of having to hard refresh the page to see the update.

This is a quick gif showing what is taking place

- https://i.gyazo.com/faefb27c2fe0fb32da097fbbf5cc1acb.mp4

I have 2 livewire components.

Parent = ViewSidebar.php / view-sidebar.blade.php

```
// view-sidebar.blade.php
@foreach ($kanbans as $kanban )
   @livewire('kanbans.show-sidebar-kanban', ['kanban'=>$kanban], key($kanban->id))
@endforeach

// ViewSidebar.php
public $kanbans;

protected $listeners = ['refreshKanbans'];
  
public function refreshKanbans()
    {
        $this->kanbans = Kanban::where('status', $this->active)
                            ->orderBy('order', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
    }

public function mount()
    {
        $this->refreshKanbans();
    }

public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.kanbans.view-sidebar');
    }
```

In the child component I set this

```
public function updateKanban($id)
    {
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);

        $id = Kanban::find($id);

        if ($id) {
            $id->update([
                'title' => $this->title,
            ]);
        }

        $this->resetInputFields();

        $this->emit('refreshKanbans');

       
    }
```

All of the files are in a subfolder called `kanbans` could this be breaking it?
[image]

Trying to follow along these docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events
[image]
[image]

I also tried this approach with calling the emit `$this->emit('updateKanbanSidebar');` and setting the listener like this `protected $listeners = ['updateKanbanSidebar' => 'refreshKanbans'];`
[image]

Clearly I am understanding the documentation wrong, but no clue where the issue is.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you certain the event in your parent component is being fired?

Comment: Thanks for the tip :), I went down the rabbit hole of different solutions after I saw the emit was getting trough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using this in the child component, and skipping the emits. I was able to DD and the emit was working properly, but not sure why it wasn't updating.

```
public function updateKanban($id)
    {
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);

        $this->kanban->update(['title' => $this->title]);

        $this->resetInputFields();

        $this->kanban=Kanban::find($this->kanban->id);
       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong in your code, so let me help you with. After emit from child (be sure this is doing well) just need have this in parent component

Parent

```
protected $listeners = ['refreshKanbans' => '$refresh'];
  
public function render()
    {
        $this->kanbans = Kanban::where('status', $this->active)
                            ->orderBy('order', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        return view('livewire.kanbans.view-sidebar');
    }
```

Let me know about

Comment: While it might not be the most efficient or appropriate, there is nothing wrong (per se) with the way @Jakub has choosen to handle the `refreshKanbans`. Calling a method and setting the `public $kanbans` property will cause a refresh as Livewire will notice a change.

Comment: Yeah, I just share I simplest way to handle that for any other case inside the parent component. I realize the incorrect "wrong" word I use before, sorry for that